# The method antMatchers(String) is undefined for the type ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry

Tags: spring-boot, runtime-error, unresolved-external

[antmatchers error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4baSI.png)

During a spring boot project I am getting the error which says 'antmatchers' cannot be resolved to a type. The antMatchers is not recognised. It is a login and register page application which has SSO login with google an github.

Comment: Which version of Spring Security are you using ? For the version Im using (6.1.3) its something like this.         
`http.cors(withDefaults()).authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorizeRequests -> {
                    authorizeRequests.requestMatchers(
                            AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/")).permitAll();
                    authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated();
                }
        );`

Comment: Got the answer. Thanks!